# How to write specific pandas data frame columns to a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have used the below code to return review data sorted by productID from a pandas data frame.

```
    #print all reviews for specific ASIN
    filtered_data1 = df.loc[df["asin"]== '0739079891', ['reviewText']]
```

How can I write the results of filtered_data1 variable directly to a CSV file?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work out.

```
filtered_data1.to_csv("myresult.csv", index = False)
```